# Date 'DD' not returning '0' in the date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a procedure which will return the year and month (number and character format) from 2 months ago.

For example, Month_2M should return the value for February, 02 but instead returns 2. This is an issue as I'm using these values to open a folder named '02. February 2021' but the current path opens '2. February 2021' which does not exist.

```
 date1 = Format(Date, "DD")

'Declaring year value of 1 month
'This is important to compare datasets from last month
If date1 > 26 Then
Year_2M = Format(Date - 67, "YYYY")

Else
Year_2M = Format(Date - 57, "YYYY")

End If

'Declaring month value of 1 month
'This is important to compare datasets from last month
If date1 > 26 Then
Month_2M = Format(Date - 67, "MM")

Else
Month_2M = Format(Date - 57, "MM")

End If

'This translates the current month from number to character format
MonthChar_2 = MonthName(Month_2M, False)
```

Comment: Running your code as posted today, the Locals window shows `Month_2M` has a value of `"02"`.    Have you declared `Month_2M` to be of some particular data type?  Or did you **not** have the option set to **require variable declaration**?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the date from 2 month ago just use the [DateAdd function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) with a *month* interval and a negative *number* argument (to subtract):

```
Dim TwoMonthAgo As Date
TwoMonthAgo = DateAdd("m", -2, Date) 'subtract 2 month from today
```

Then use `Day(TwoMonthAgo)`, `Month(TwoMonthAgo)` and `Year(TwoMonthAgo)` to get day and month as numeric values:

```
Dim DayNumeric As Long
DayNumeric = Day(TwoMonthAgo)

Dim MonthNumeric As Long
MonthNumeric = Month(TwoMonthAgo)

Dim YearNumeric As Long
YearNumeric = Year(TwoMonthAgo)
```

Or use the `Format` function if you need a string with leading zeros:

```
Dim DayString As String
DayString = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "dd")

Dim MonthString As String
MonthString = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "mm")

Dim YearString As String
YearString = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "yyyy")
```

Or any other fancy date format:

```
Dim ISO8601_Format As String
ISO8601_Format = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: @FunThomas correct was about to add it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ for the above - however its still returning '2' instead of '02'. Any idea on why this might be?

Comment: @Danny where is it returning `2`? This `DayString = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "dd")` would return `02` not `2`

Comment: @FunThomas Format returns a string - not ideal when you want to compare it to an integer `date1 > 26`.

Comment: `Month_2M = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "mm")` returns 2 instead of 02. @KostasK. is correct - when I changed `Month_2M` to a String, it returned 02.

Comment: @Danny Of course numeric `02` is the same as `2` numeric a `02` does not exist. Mathematically there is no difference between `02` and `2`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes but my issue isn't a mathematical issue - my procedure is intended to look for a folder named '02. February' not '2. February'.

Comment: @Danny Well then use something like `MonthString = Format$(TwoMonthAgo, "dd. mmmm")` this will directly output `02. February`

Answer (score 1):

Adding and removing months is actually a pretty common task in VBA. These are the functions I am using for it:

```
Public Function GetLastDayOfMonth(ByVal myDate As Date) As Date
    GetLastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate) + 1, 0)
End Function

Public Function GetFirstDayOfMonth(ByVal myDate As Date) As Date
    GetFirstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1)
End Function

Public Function AddMonths(ByVal myDate As Date, ByVal lngMonth As Long) As Date
    AddMonths = GetLastDayOfMonth(DateAdd("m", lngMonth, myDate))
End Function

Public Function AddMonthsAndGetFirstDate(ByVal my_date As Date, ByVal lngMonth As Long) As Date
    AddMonthsAndGetFirstDate = GetFirstDayOfMonth(DateAdd("m", lngMonth, my_date))
End Function

Public Function DateDiffInMonths(a As Date, b As Date) As Long
    DateDiffInMonths = DateDiff("m", a, b)
End Function

Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print GetLastDayOfMonth(DateSerial(2020, 2, 22))
    Debug.Print GetLastDayOfMonth(DateSerial(2021, 2, 22))        
    Debug.Print GetFirstDayOfMonth(DateSerial(2021, 2, 22))
    Debug.Print AddMonths(DateSerial(2020, 2, 23), 3)
    Debug.Print AddMonthsAndGetFirstDate(DateSerial(2020, 2, 23), 3)        
    Debug.Print DateDiffInMonths(DateSerial(1988, 8, 18), DateSerial(1998, 10, 18))
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Format:

```
FolderName = Format(DateAdd("m", -2, Date), "mm\. mmmm yyyy")
```